# Website goes offline for a period of time

Tags: apache-2.4, google-cloud-platform

My website went down yesterday in the moment of a launch when 200 people accessed the landing page.

I use Cloudflare, so they show what the problem was about and it's marked as "host" with the given error:

> Error 524;
>   Error 521.

I shut down the machine and then started it back up.  Apparently it did work, but how can I be sure it is not going to happen again? I really thought that GCP was robust.

Do you guys have some thoughts about how can help and secure that this will not happening again?

ps. I did know this isn't a cloudflare problem, I've try to reach out my webserver, but sadly I'm bronze and have the right of support, so I've come here :)

Comment: This is an error about _your_ webserver, which was unreachable at that time. No problem on Cloudflares side. Check your own logs

Comment: I did know this isn't a cloudflare problem, I've try to reach out my webserver, but sadly I don't like "platinum" support, so I've come here.

Comment: check the lohs and or post em

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with GCP, but if you need to, you can contact them via chat, even if you don't have a support package. This is the link: https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat

Comment: GCP is robust. Your particular setup may not be. Load test your code, figure out where your bottlenecks are, and optimize/cache/improve where necessary. You may find you need more server capacity, or configuration changes that make it easier for CloudFlare to cache your page.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks everyone for answering. I've setted properly this time and checked for loading problems (still improving the page speed), but I didn't figure what caused this issue. Hope this problem was solved with this setup.